# How to find all opened tags using regular expression

Tags: c#, xml, regex

```
<meals>
    <breakfast>
         Eggs and Toast
    </breakfast>
    <lunch>
         Salad and soup
```

this is my XML.I just wanted to get Opened Tag(Lunch,Meals) from this xml using regular expression.
Please help me.

Comment: What have you already attempted?

Comment: var pattern1 = "(?<open><(?<tag>[a-z]+)>)([^<]+?)";

Answer (score 0):

This answer is [a bit more to the point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) (it's about HTML, but concerns XML as well).

If this does not scare you, at least try to make the question more specific (is this just one kind of XML? what "meals"?)

Answer (score 0):

To get the data between a right and left angle bracket (where the left bracket is not succeeded by a forward slash), you can use the following expression:

```
<([^<>/]+)>
```

...where the first (and only) capture group will contain the name of the tag; "group 0" will contain the whole match--name and brackets.